# Recursively walk values in Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10, scalaz

I am attempting to walk a `Map[String,List[String]]` recursively to extract and flatten all values associated with a Map

```
val x = Map("a" -> List("b","c","d"), "b" -> List("f","g","h"), "f" -> List("i","j","k"), "g" -> List("p","q","r"))
```

1. For each of the keys, extract values i.e. List
2. For each item in values of List:

   - Check if key exists and then extract values

Continue to do so recursively till the keys have no values and flatten values of list for key

The result should be

```
Map("a" -> List("b","c","d","f","g","h","i","j","k","p","q","r"), 
    "b" ->  List("f","g","h","i","j","k","p","q","r"), 
    "f" -> List("i","j","k"), 
    "g" -> List("p","q","r"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to iterate until there is no change:

```
def getValues(dict: Map[String, List[String]]) = Iterator.iterate(dict) { _.mapValues { 
        _.flatMap(v => v :: dict.get(v).toList.flatten).toSet.toList
    } filterNot { _._2.isEmpty }
}.sliding(2) find { x => x.head == x.last }
```

This definitely is not the most efficient solution, but it is pretty terse!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
def f(map: Map[String, List[String]]): Map[String, List[String]] = {
  def f(x: Map[String, List[String]], acc: Map[String, List[String]]): Map[String, List[String]] = {
    if (x.isEmpty) acc
    else {
      val keys = x.keySet
      val (complex, simple) = x partition {_._2 exists {s => keys contains s}}

      val newX =
        (for ((ck, cl) <- complex)
        yield (ck -> (simple.filter(x => cl.contains (x._1)).map(_._2).flatten ++ cl).toList)).toMap

      f(newX, acc ++ simple)
    }
  }

  f(map, Map.empty)
}

val x = Map("a" -> List("b","c","d"), "b" -> List("f", "g", "h"), "f" -> List("i","j","k"), "g" -> List("p","q","r"))

println(f(x)) //Map(f -> List(i, j, k), g -> List(p, q, r), b -> List(i, j, k, p, q, r, f, g, h), a -> List(i, j, k, p, q, r, f, g, h, b, c, d))
```

However it is assumed that there is no recursion in the map e.g. `("a" -> List("b")), ("b" -> List("a")`. If it happens the function will end up in infinite loop. You would have to add extra code to handle such situations.